# Vue/Quasar, Webpack, These relative modules were not found in node_modules

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework

I've bootstrapped  an app with `quasar` framework (based on vuejs 2). I installed some package which need some dependencies. When i try to use the package (`leboncoin-api`) i got this error :

> These relative modules were not found:
>   * ./types/other in ./node_modules/mime/index.js
>   * ./types/standard in ./node_modules/mime/index.js

I have checked in `node_modules` and those files exist. They are imported in `index` file in mime looking like this :

```
'use strict';

var Mime = require('./Mime');
module.exports = new Mime(require('./types/standard'), require('./types/other'));
```

I tried quickly with `create-react-app` and the package is working. I've read that it can come from `webpack`, but i'm struggling to correct it. I have no idea where to look :/

Here is the part of `webpack` that maybe can help :

```
extendWebpack(cfg) {
   cfg.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
   });
},
```

I tried with and without excluding `node_modules`, same error

Thanks in advance from the community for the help !

EDIT :
I added to wepack.config

```
resolve: {
      modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
 },
```

Which change the error to :

> This relative module was not found:
>
> - ./package in ./node_modules/leboncoin-api/node_modules/cheerio/index.js